# Spring Integration channel() distributes messages to unexpected subscribers

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

currently I facing some issue with Spring IntegrationFlows and the channel() method.
I'm not sure what I have miss understood something or if there is a bug in the framework.

Here is the Flow:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(makeFinal = true, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class ImportFlow {


    ConsumerFactory<String, String> kafkaConsumerFactory;
    ServiceProperties serviceProperties;

    DebugHandler debugHandler;

    DebugSecondHandler secondHandler;

    TombstoneHandler tombstoneHandler;

    @Bean
    public StandardIntegrationFlow startKafkaInbound() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from(Kafka
                .messageDrivenChannelAdapter(
                    kafkaConsumerFactory,
                    ListenerMode.record,
                    serviceProperties.getImportTopic().getName())
            )
            .channel(Objects.requireNonNull(routeKafkaMessage().getInputChannel()))
            .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow routeKafkaMessage() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from("routeKafkaMessage.input")
            .route(Message.class,
                p -> {
                    if (p.getPayload().equals(KafkaNull.INSTANCE)) {
                        return processTombstoneFlow().getInputChannel();
                    }
                    return someSplittingFlow().getInputChannel();
                })
            .get();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow someSplittingFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from("someSplittingFlow.input")
            .handle(debugHandler)
            .channel(sendToFlow().getInputChannel())
            .get();
    }


    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow processTombstoneFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from("processTombstoneFlow.input")
            .handle(tombstoneHandler)
            .channel(sendToFlow().getInputChannel())
        .handle(unexpectedHandler) // Whatever you do here besides a direct get() will lead to an error 
            // .nullChannel()
            .handle(m -> {})
            .get();
    }


    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow sendToFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from("sendToFlow.input")
            .handle(secondHandler)
            .handle(m -> {}, e -> e.id("endOfSendToFlow"))
            .get();
    }

}
```

If I send 100 messages with Payload to kafka only 50 messages are received by the *secondHandler* in the sendToFlow.
The other 50 messages are received by the *unexpectedHandler*
Somehow I expected, that all messages would be send to the sendToFlow.

From the logs it can be seen that each second massage was send to the tombstoneFlow:

> org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel: preSend on channel 'bean 'processTombstoneFlow.channel#0'

It worked also vice versa. If I send 100 Messages with *null* (KafkaNull) only the half reaching the *sencondHandler*.

I was expecting that there are two DirectChannel only connecting *someSplittingFlow<->sendToFlow* or *processTombstoneFlow<->sendToFlow*

What I do not understand is how and why *someSplittingFlow* and *processTombstoneFlow* get connected.

I also added once a third channel to send something to the *sendToFlow*. Then only 33% of the messages reached the expected channel.

I put the demo app  [here](https://github.com/JonathanHel/ExampleSplitChannel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `MessageChannel` type in Spring Integration is a `DirectChannel`. That is, for example, a result of your `IntegrationFlow.from("sendToFlow.input")`. This channel comes with a round-robin strategy which means that subscribed message handlers are going to get every message for only one next subscriber.

In your case that `sendToFlow.input` got one subscriber from that `sendToFlow()`, essentially yours `.handle(secondHandler)`. And then you do this in the `processTombstoneFlow()`:

```
    .channel(sendToFlow().getInputChannel())
    .handle(unexpectedHandler)
```

Which means that you subscribe this `unexpectedHandler` as a second one for the same channel. Therefore your round-robin behavior.

We need to know more about your logic to determine some steps how to fix the situation.

See more info in docs about that channel: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/channel/implementations.html#channel-implementations-directchannel

Comment: Thanks  for that explanation. 

What we do is: 
After the KafkaNull or the Kafka record handling we have some Common Stuff like informing other application about the State (KafkaNull -> deleted else Update)

Both channel uses the sendToFlow as subchannel. And at least one channel needs to get the result to do some further processing.

At least for testing it works with 
```
            .publishSubscribeChannel(publishSubscribeSpec -> publishSubscribeSpec
                .subscribe(flow -> flow.channel(Objects.requireNonNull(sendToFlow().getInputChannel())))
            )
```

Comment: So, the `publishSubscribeChannel()` is the correct way to fix this problem then. One of the subscribers is going to send a message to this `channel(Objects.requireNonNull(sendToFlow().getInputChannel())))` and another one really could be your `.handle(unexpectedHandler)` as it is right now. You just need to change a single like in that `processTombstoneFlow`: instead of `.channel(sendToFlow().getInputChannel())` use a `publishSubscribeChannel()`.